# Repeater Container.DataItem vs Item

Tags: asp.net, repeater, asprepeater

I'm working on a project that uses Container.DataItem in ascx files inside of repeaters a lot. Is there a difference between using Container.DataItem and casting it vs Item if the ItemType declared for the repeater?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="uxListRelated" runat="server" ItemType="System.String">
  <ItemTemplate>
      <%# (System.String)Container.DataItem %>
      <%# Item %>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I'm not really sure where I can look for the source for either Container or Item. Sure Container is a repeater item and Item seems to be the DataItem cast but I'm not exactly sure how it's a valid thing to databind inside of the repeater, I've pretty much taken it for granted. If anyone has any insight on the inner workings of asp.net it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Interested by this question too. Did you find an answer?

Comment: @Denis unfortunately I did not.

Answer (score 0):

It is the same object but one is casted to your type so you can access directly its properties.
Using ItemType is much more convenient because it's shorter. We've replaced all of them in a big project. No problem at all, only easier to read.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).